# Django 1.8.7 get_readonly_fields seems like have a bug

Tags: python, django, get, field, readonly

I try something with readonly field in Django 1.8.7, let say I have some code like the following:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('a', 'b')

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.readonly_fields += ('c')
        return super(MyAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
```

first I login with super admin and access that admin page change_form,

the code is works well, then I login with staff user, then still works well, again, I try login with superadmin, but the read only fields rendered is for the non-superadmin user,

again I clear the browser cache, try again with super admin, but still not work correctly. I try restart the server, then it work normally until I repeat the same step above I do, this weird thing come again.

Anyone know why this happen ? I think this is looks like some bug but not sure.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is not in Django, but in your code. In your `get_readonly_fields` method you *modify* the `readonly_fields` attribute; those modifications persist, since the admin object lives for the lifetime of the process.

Don't do that. `get_readonly_fields` is supposed to return a value, not modify the attribute. Just do:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    rfo = super(MyAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        rfo += ('c')
    return rfo
```

Comment: Nice answer!!! Thanks a lot. I don't see if my code is buggy, then you proof it. thanks for your description about this.